# Sticky footer animation with jquery and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, settimeout

I try to make animation for sticky footer, indeed, it is a horizontal ribbon using jquery and setTimeout. I just want to animate that ribbon's background color.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="ribbon">
    <div class="closeR" style="display:inline-block; width:2.9em; height:1.8em; float:right; margin-right:0.7em; cursor: pointer;" title="إغلاق">X</div>    <a href="/viewAyah/192">كل عام وأنتم بخير... رمضان الطاعات</a>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.ribbon {
    z-index: 10;
    border: 1px solid #faa;
    background-color: #a00;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    /*bottom bar*/
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /* shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -2px 6px #525252;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -2px 6px #525252;
}
.ribbon a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 81.25%'sans-serif;
 margin: 0.05em 0 0.075em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* shadow */
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #444;
}
```

**And Finally the Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('ribbonClose')) {
        $('.ribbon').css("display", "none");

    } else {
        state = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (state) {
                $(".ribbon").animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#ff0"
                }, 100);
                state = false;
            } else {
                $(".ribbon").animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#050"
                }, 100);
                state = true;
            }
        }, 50);

    }

    $('.closeR').click(function () {
        $('.ribbon').fadeOut("slow");
        $.cookie('ribbonClose', true, {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
    })
})
```

The animation does not work! It seems that setTimeout does not able to recall the defined function every 50 millisecond, it just call the function once! What is the mistake here?

### There is a [live demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/esff7/2/)

Comment: Don't you confuse it with `setInterval()`?

Comment: the above comment by sємsєм is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/esff7/10/

Comment: Well Done! but what does make setTimeout not be working?!

Comment: @sємsєм If you use setTimeOut you need to call setTimeOut within the same function again to get the setInterval effect. Set timeout executes only once after the delay. SetInterval executes is after every interval that you mentioned. Look at [setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)